# Open pinned site in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, internet-explorer-11, file-shortcut

A website that I need to access for work only works in Internet Explorer 11. I can create a shortcut to this website and place it on my desktop or taskbar, but it always opens in Edge, which is my default browser.

Is there any way I can modify the shortcut so that it forces it to open in IE11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the internet shortcut, because a `.url` is a different format from a `.lnk`. However, you can create a `.lnk` - it's a regular program shortcut - where the target is `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "<insert URL here>"`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create and save a batch (.bat) file such that the url inserted always directed to IE:

```
@echo_off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "<insert your url here>"
exit
```

2. Create a shortcut (.lnk) file to it so as to modified the file properties such as icon to what you wanted to be.

Answer (score -1):

It is relatively simple to accomplish what you want to do. In the Program Files or Program Files (X86) folder, find the Internet Explorer program (iexplore.exe). Drag that program to your desktop (or if you have Windows 10, you can right click on the iexplorer.exe file in its original folder and you'll find a Menu Item labeled "Send to." Click on that and you'll see another menu item "Desktop (create shortcut)". That will move an iexplorer shortcut to the desktop. Now what you have to do is right click on the iexplorer shortcut and choose properties. You'll see a Target Box that will already have this text in it: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" at the end of that command, put in a space and then type in the name of the website that you want to launch with Internet Explorer. you will have a script that looks something like this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" https:\Your website of interest. First click Apply. and then click on the modified file and load the website that you want to launch with Internet Explorer. Good luck! It worked for me; so it should for you.

Comment: This was already suggested.

Comment: Apologies, It was not my intent to repeat another user's answer. I didn't read Ramhound's suggestion close enough. Sorry!

Comment: Wasn’t my suggestion or was it my answer